# Serve Mobile Application in Subdomain For Existing CodeIgniter Site

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a main site (www.example.com) built on CI. Lately I thought of creating a mobile version of the site on mobile subdomain (m.example.com) with different view using JQuery mobile but wanted to use most of the codes from my main app (specially models. Queries for both are same).

Thinking and implementation process was exactly same as what had been stated here
[Redirecting to mobile subdomain in a CI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967794/redirecting-to-mobile-subdomain-in-a-ci-application)

I had:

```
controller  
home.php (for main site)  
mobile.php (for mobile site)
```

With few research I was able to do a trick with "config.php" and "routes.php" like this.

```
[config.php]
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com';
$config['mobile_url']   = 'http://m.example.com';


[routes.php]

switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'm.example.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "mobile";
    break;
    default:
        $route['default_controller'] = "home";
    break;
}
```

So far this looks fine but under the hood it doesn't function as I expected.

when I go to m.example.com, it loads mobile version of the site just fine but I can't go further from there. For example I wanted to implement search function on this mobile version of the site but can't implement sub functions for this sub domain.

```
m.example.com/search/term
```

simply didn't work. It executes the main site instead and renders the main site's view.

This works more like a sub page of main site (www.example.com/mobile) rather than the different application in different domain.

Now I am thinking of creating separate application for mobile version on same CI installation

let's say

```
system
mainsite
mobilesite
www
```

My questions:

1) What is the best way to create mobile version of the app where I can reuse the code from main application? Should I stay with my old approach (with redirection to controller) or build separate application?

2) If two separate application is the way to go, how do I redirect to right version of index.php file for right application based the domain name. i.e, if user types www.example.com it goes to main site, while m.example.com should redirect to mobile version. Currently I have main app running on site with one index.php.

I really appreciate some suggestion and tips.

By the way I have googled a bit about this topic but couldn't find definitive answer for what I am trying to do.

I have found something like

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330

but I am not after serving same application on differnt sub-domain instead I wanted to create separate application for a sub domain.

This topic
[Is there an easy way to create subdomains on codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873554/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-subdomains-on-codeigniter) seems to be going somewhere but its not clear to me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that I was tackling the problem with wrong approach.

Actually this solved the problem and this is what I exactly wanted.

1. Created a mobile sub-domain form my hosting cPanel.
2. Created **1:1** desktop site view equivalent for mobile site.
3. Used [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) script as helper and based on the detected device, routed to proper view.

Thank you all... hope this helps.